# Creating a list of lists using operations with elements from another list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists

```
angles_rad = [[0.873,0.874,0.875...],[0.831,0.832, ...],...]
```

and I would like to create a new list of lists, where I subtract all the angles in each inner list from the angles before them:

```
ang_velocity = [[(0.874-0.873)/2,(0.875-0.874)/2,...],[(0.832-0.831)/2, ...],...]
```

How can I do this?

The lengths of the inner lists are all different. My attempt was the following:

```
angular_velocity = []
for i in range(374):
    for j in range all:
        alist = []
        for angle1, angle2 in zip(orientations[i][j],orientations[i][j+1]):
            alist.append((angle2 - angle1)/2)
    angular_velocity.append(alist)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html ?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You want to zip *the list with a slice of itself starting from index 1*. So:

```
In [1]: angles_rad = [[0.873,0.874,0.875],[0.831,0.832]]
   ...: [[f"({y} - {x})/2" for x,y in zip(sub, sub[1:])] for sub in angles_rad]
   ...:
   ...:
Out[1]: [['(0.874 - 0.873)/2', '(0.875 - 0.874)/2'], ['(0.832 - 0.831)/2']]
```

I created a string for clarity, but just replace my string interpolation with the actual expression.

In general, **do not iterate over `range(len(...)))`** unless you *actually need the indices*. You don't need the indices, you need the *values*, so just iterate over things directly. Using for-loops:

```
In [2]: final = []

In [3]: for sub in angles_rad:
   ...:     intermediate = []
   ...:     for x, y in zip(sub, sub[1:]):
   ...:         intermediate.append((y - x)/2)
   ...:     final.append(intermediate)
   ...:

In [4]: final
Out[4]: [[0.0005000000000000004, 0.0005000000000000004], [0.0005000000000000004]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This very elegently solves my problem. :)

Comment: Ah wait. There's a problem. All the inner lists are the same. They should all have different values

Comment: @IwanPhillips they are all the same because they all have the same result when applying the operation. My example with the string interpolation was meant to be clear on that point

Comment: @IwanPhillips iow, you chose examples where all values `x - y` are `0.001`

Comment: I just noticed that thanks. When I use this code for a few values it works perfectly, but if a use this code for a large amount of data all my inner lists have the same values. I think the problem must have something to do with my data though.

Comment: Actually having looked at my large amount of data more closely I can see that all the different inner lists are being created but they're all being created many many times like  [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],...[6,7,8,9],[6,7,8,9],[6,7,8,9],...]. Hmmm.

Comment: If I remove all the repeats with itertools then I'm left with the lists I want, so it's not a terrible problem.

Comment: @IwanPhillips so, not entirely sure what you are talking about. Remeber, I have no context except what you posted in your question. But, yeah, I agree, it seems like some problem with however you are generating these lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing in a nested list comprehension:

```
angles_rad = [[0.873,0.874,0.875],[0.831,0.832]]
new_angles = [[(b[i+1]-b[i])/float(2) for i in range(len(b)-1)] for b in angles_rad]
```